# Aligning equations in `align`

Tags: equations, align

I wanted something aligned like the following:
[image]

All equations are aligned at $\to$, while the top two equations are aligned at `countingUp`.
The middle two equations are aligned at `counter`.
The last equation is center-aligned, like `gather`.

Here is the base for what I have:

```tex
\begin{align*}
    countingUp \wedge counter < 100 &\to [counter \leftarrow counter + 1] \\
    \neg countingUp \wedge counter > 0 &\to [counter \leftarrow counter - 1] \\
    counter = 100 &\to \neg countingUp \\
    counter = 0 &\to countingUp \\
    0 \leq~&counter \leq 100
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `alignat*` to choose the alignment points manually. A little trickery is needed for the last line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \mathit{countingUp} \wedge \mathit{counter} &< 100 &&\to [\mathit{counter} \leftarrow \mathit{counter} + 1] \\
    \neg \mathit{countingUp} \wedge \mathit{counter} &> 0 &&\to [\mathit{counter} \leftarrow \mathit{counter} - 1] \\
    \mathit{counter} &= 100 &&\to \neg \mathit{countingUp} \\
    \mathit{counter} &= 0 &&\to \mathit{countingUp} \\
    0 &\leq \mathrlap{\mathit{counter} \leq 100}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did not know about the `mathtools` package. Thank you.

Comment: @gust `mathtools` is needed for the `\mathrlap` macro. You can obtain the same with `amsmath` alone with `\makebox`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gather*` and the first four lines in a nested `align*`, but the result would not be pretty.

You can make the last row to be half before the arrow and half after it.

In the code, `\tv` stands for “textual variable”. Using a semantic command will allow to change the typographical realization of all these objects in one swoop by modifying just the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tv}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tv{countingUp} \wedge \tv{counter} < 100
  &\to [\tv{counter} \leftarrow \tv{counter} + 1] \\
\neg \tv{countingUp} \wedge \tv{counter} > 0
  &\to [\tv{counter} \leftarrow \tv{counter} - 1] \\
\tv{counter} = 100
  &\to \neg \tv{countingUp} \\
\tv{counter} = 0
  &\to \tv{countingUp} \\
&\makebox[0.5\width][r]{$\hphantom{\to{}}0 \leq counter \leq 100$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd consider left alignment, though.

```
\begin{align*}
& \tv{countingUp} \wedge \tv{counter} < 100 \to [\tv{counter} \leftarrow \tv{counter} + 1] \\
& \neg \tv{countingUp} \wedge \tv{counter} > 0 \to [\tv{counter} \leftarrow \tv{counter} - 1] \\
& \tv{counter} = 100 \to \neg \tv{countingUp} \\
& \tv{counter} = 0 \to \tv{countingUp} \\
& 0 \leq counter \leq 100
\end{align*}
```

[image]